# How to save firebase cloud messaging tokens?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Im trying to use firebase cloud messaging to enable push notifications on my PWA.
but i can't figure out how to save tokens after the 'user' click on 'accept' on the push notification subscription message.
Should i save token to a firebase database? or there is a automatic system to subscribe/unsubscribe/ clean the list of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean registration tokens? If so, please check out this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) which has comprehensive information about how to manage registration tokens.